# Netsuite Timsheet feature not enabled error even though it should be enabled

Tags: api, integration, netsuite

I'm trying to create a timesheet in Netsuite programmatically through API calls but I get "Timesheet featured is not enabled" error even though I checked possibly all timesheet related checkbox features under Setup-->Company-->Enable feature are checked. Anyone has seen this before?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of all the setup required for the new Timesheets module, but be aware that NetSuite is removing all SuiteScript access to Timesheets with 2015.2. They are completely overhauling how the module works, so once 2015.2 is released, any scripting around Timesheets will cease to function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process of enabling Timesheets feature
Published 04/22/2014 11:20 AM   |    Updated 01/29/2015 12:41 PM      |    Answer Id: 38014
1)      Customer requests enabling of Timesheets feature via technical support  ('Two Administrators' or an 'Administrator and a Primary contact' or an 'Administrator and a Decision Maker' should sign off in writing that they understood the repercussion of enabling this feature. And they would want this feature to be enabled on their account.)
2)      Checkbox for Timesheets is available on Enable features page
3)      Customer (Admin) enables the feature
-          Notification appears with checking of the box:

4)      Customer saves the preferences
5)      While migration takes place, Time Tracking box is checked
-          It is not possible to change feature setup during migration, following notification pops up if someone tries to do so:

6)      When migration is complete
a)      Timesheets box is checked
b)      E-mail is delivered once migration is successfully complete
Subject: The Timesheet feature has been enabled
Body: The Timesheet feature has been enabled and the system has finished updating your Time Tracking custom fields and time transactions.
-          if migration fails, e-mail is also sent, notifying admin about failure

As for the estimated time, it depends on amount of data that are migrated. To give you at least some rough estimate, we are talking about hours here. Small customers can be migrated within hour, larger ones couple of hours. If the process of enabling/disabling the feature takes 2 days or more, please contact NetSuite Support.

Comment: That's very helpful, Vijay, thanks for your response very much!